# Serf 1.3.8 install using scons is failing

Tags: http, svn, scons

I am using Redhat 6.6 and installed scons and using scons to install serf 1.3.8 but seeing the below error. Anyone has faced the below error. I am stuck and i need serf for http/https access for svn 1.9. Seeking advice for below error. I followed below URL. "http://www.linuxfromscratch.org" site for install procedure. I see error while executing cmd "/local//scons-2.4.1/script/scons check"
Has anyone know the solution or alternative to install serf to bypass this option and install serf without no issues

```
scons: Building targets ... test/test_buckets.c: In function 
'test_deflate_4GBplus_buckets': test/test_buckets.c:1559: warning: integer 
overflow in expression scons: *** [test/test_buckets.o] Error 1 scons: building 
terminated because of errors.
```

Please advice.

[EDIT]
What env variables are required for scons to work properly. I see different error, i messed the environment. Seeing the below error. Any idea what I have missed. I have the custom install for python7.  I have added the python install path to PATH,LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Error is below. Import failed. Unable to find SCons files in:   /local/appln/pkgs/scons-2.4.1/bin/../engine   /local/appln/pkgs/scons-2.4.1/bin/scons-local-2.4.1 /local/appln/pkgs/scons-2.4.1/bin/scons-local  /usr/lib/scons-2.4.1 /usr/local/lib/scons-2.4.1  /local/apps/pkgs/scons-2.4.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scons-2.4.1   /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scons-2.4.1 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scons-2.4.1 /usr/lib64/scons-2.4.1  /local/apps/pkgs/scons-2.4.1/lib/scons /usr/lib/scons /usr/local/lib/scons /local/appln/pkgs/scons-2.4.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scons /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scons
  /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scons /usr/lib64/scons
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/local/appln/pkgs/scons-2.4.1/bin/scons", line 190, in  import SCons.Script
ImportError: No module named SCons.Script

[Closed]

Comment: Looks like this: https://code.google.com/p/serf/issues/detail?id=156  can you use a newer version?

Comment: @bdbaddog - i am using the serf 1.3.8 which is the latest version. This version is required for svn 1.9.2(latest). The project owner in that post has  said it is fixed in branch 1.3.x but still it is not compiling. i am struck any workaround for this problem.

Comment: You could just go to that source file and comment out the test_deflate_4GBplus_buckets and it's references.. Or find the line in that function which is causing the issue.  But if you're just trying to build it and can live with skipping that one test, commenting it out would a fast hack to get it done.

Comment: @bdbaddog - As suggested by scons dev team, I have skipped the scons check step and ran the scons install, but bin directory was not installed in scons install directory and due to which svn install is failing.

Comment: The path to scons/script file was missing. After adding the svn configure script went successfully. I check with scons dev team, since its a library no bin directory will be available. Finally worked.